# What happens to a thread as soon as it has completed its assigned task in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

I have been working on a project in which my program creates around 500 threads during the execution. I find that my PC starts taking a huge load as soon as the program I execute the program. And it continues showing load after 75% of the threads have completed their job.
I want to know whether the threads whose work has finished were killed or not. And how does java deal with threads which have finished their job. Any help...

Comment: Have you considered a different design, e.g. submitting your tasks to a fixed (or limited size) `ThreadPoolExecutor` rather than giving each one its own thread?

Comment: Could you elaborate on computations involved? There a not that many cases (i.e. crawling) when you need 500 simultaneous threads...

Comment: I have been developing an application that scans network for the shared resources.I have used a separate thread for each node on the network to check the shared resources and if there are shared resources on the node(which I check with the help of jCIFS), a thread within that thread will run to walk the tree of the shared folders and store the info  in local filesystem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> I find that my PC starts taking a huge load as soon as the program I execute the program. And it continues showing load after 75% of the threads have completed their job.

If 75% of the 500 threads have completed their job then that leaves 100+ threads that continue to run.  100 threads, if using a good amount of CPU, can more than swamp the processors on a box which I assume does not have 100s of cores.  So your application may continue to show 100% CPU utilization until the number of running threads drops below the number of cores.

You should consider using a fixed sized thread pool instead of creating 500 concurrent threads.  You then submit 500 *tasks* to the thread pool.  This allows you to choose an appropriate number of threads to be running concurrently.  The appropriate number of threads is highly dependent on the tasks being submitted.  More CPU bound tasks should use fewer threads while IO bound tasks can use more.  Doing some test runs with your application while adjusting the number of threads is the best way to optimize the value.  I tend to start with 2 times the number of cores and then optimize from there.

```
// create a thread pool with 10 workers
ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
// define your jobs somehow
for (MyRunnable job : jobsToDo) {
    threadPool.submit(job);
}
// once we have submitted all jobs to the thread pool, it should be shutdown
threadPool.shutdown();
```

For more details, check out the [`ExecutorService` tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/exinter.html).

> I want to know whether the threads whose work has finished were killed or not. And how does java deal with threads which have finished their job. Any help...

The threads have most likely finished.  After a thread leaves the `run()` method (either because it returns or throws an exception) it will no longer consume CPU and its underlying native thread can be reaped or reused.  If there are no references to the `Thread` object, its memory will eventually be reaped by the garbage collector.

Answer (score 4):

The JVM will garbage collect the `Thread` object, as long as there are    no references to it, and as long as its run method returns. Thread is    dead itself after its run method returns. It might still be in the    heap, but it will not have its own stack anymore, and not do anything.

The only possible way that your threads have not been killed is that    they still do something or you forgot to clean up references to your    thread objects - but this is memory related.

If you allocated your threads through the thread pool, they are returned to the pool after the execution of the task. I this case, they might not be released after the completion of the task.

Answer (score 1):

we should not create many threads to accomplish our task, it will give you many issues like OutofMemoryError. And also creation of thread is a costly task, so we should think of Thread pool i.e. `ExecutorService` in which we reuse the same threads again and again.

But any ways to answer you question after threads are created they die automatically i.e. it will be garbage collected, you don't need to do anything. Initially java provided methods like `stop()` or `destroy()` but these are deprecated for good reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can read about a [Thread's lifecycle](http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/docs/tutorial/essential/threads/lifecycle.html). If the run method is over then they should not be consuming your cpu.

Answer (score 0):

Threads who have finished their jobs will die. It won't consume any more CPU time.

You can use [`jstack`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html)  to check how many threads are active running in your java process.